# Angular flex layout margins on the side

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

What is the best way to add margins on the far left and far right with angular/flex-layout?

I am using `fxLayoutGap="24px"` but it doesn't do the sides. Do I just drop to regular CSS? it appears  `fxLayoutGap="24px grid"` should work but it doesn't.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the output?

Comment: I guess `fxLayoutAlign="space-around"` would help.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding statements like "What is the best way..." It seems reasonable but in many cases invites opinion rather that fact and can even invite close/down votes on principle. "How do I..." is likely a better approach.